# Is it possible to create EC2 with enabled Elastic Inference using Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am starting to learn about Elastic inference and thought about if it is possible to create Elastic Inference enabled instances via Elastic Beanstalk?

I thought that it might be possible if:
1)Create EC2 with necessary configurations
2)Take the EC2 AMI
2)Add it to Elastic Beanstalk

But I am only starting to do some test in this way.
Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to create instances with elastic inference through elastic beanstalk, and was wondering if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not possible right now.

[Here is the answer](https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/81)